# Your session has expired main home page magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3.0

Go to home page and add to cart product and then this time error is come Your Session Has Expired
I also try to change pen PHPMYADMIN
run:
`UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 864000 WHERE path = 'admin/security/session_lifetime'` but not working tell me how to find this solution

Comment: this is not helping on a website running at my hosting partner.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158020)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1.
Run below two lines in console:

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/"
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://127.0.0.1/"
```